# How to get list of classes with specific prefix from a result of another selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selector that gets all elements by certain condition:

```
let elements = $("...");
```

This results in a list of elements whose one of their classes has the same prefix:

`some_class_1`, `some_class_2` and so on.

I then want to hide all elements that have the same class with addition:

`some_class_1extra`, `some_class_2extra`

For that I want to extract all the classes with this specific prefix, then iterate them and add the extra text and select the elements I want to hide for each.

How can I do it?

The following did not work:

```
let classes =  elements.map(function() {
                return (this.className.match(/some_class\d+/) || []).pop();
            }).get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: Your regex missed a `_` character, use: `/some_class_\d+/` instead.

If you have a **collection** array of jQuery objects (elements) and you want to create a subset collection based on a className prefix, use the [.filter() method](https://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
const $elements = $(".box");

// Create a subset collection of .box elements matching a prefix className
const $classes = $elements.filter((i, el) => el.className.match(/some_class_\d+/));

// jQuery collection with two $ objects elements
console.log($classes);
```

```html
<div class="box some_class_1 cell">one</div>
<div class="box cell">ignore</div>
<div class="box some_class_2 demo">two</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now that you have that subset, you can change the element's classNames.

Use `className` and [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a small regex to match your specific class string prefix and replace the match with that same match *and* your desired suffix.
In this example I'm adding `_extra` as suffix, since it's easier to select in CSS :)

```js
const $elements = $(".box");

// Create a subset collection of .box elements matching a prefix className
const $classes = $elements.filter((i, el) => el.className.match(/some_class_\d+/));

// Iterate the jQuery collection with two $Object elements
// and modify the classNames:
$classes.each((i, el) => {
  el.className = el.className.replace(/\b(some_class_\d+)\b/, "$1_extra");
});
```

```css
/* Target classes by prefix: */

[class^="some_class_"],
[class*=" some_class_"] {
  background: red;
}


/* Target classes by suffix: */

[class*="_extra "],
[class$="_extra"] {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box some_class_1 cell">one</div>
<div class="box cell">ignore</div>
<div class="box some_class_2 demo">two</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. However it's not exactly what I need in my case. I get list of jQuery objects from the first selector. I need to match each class to the one with extra suffix. Including the numbers. Because I want specifically those with the exact number. In my example it should find the extra elements with numbers 1 and 2 otherwise it will match all classes but I want specifically to those that matched the first jQuery selector

Comment: The above works as expected. As you can see the `_extra` class is added.

Comment: But I need to iterate those elements only from the list of matched elements saved in `elements`. Otherwise it will match all `some_class_x`, even those that were not matched by the initial selector (there can be `some_class_222`, `some_class_123`, and so on, but I need to match only the ones found in `elements`

Comment: @Stackerito Oh, makes more sense now. I'll edit the answer. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @Stackerito edited. As you can notice the answer is not much different than before besides the first part regarding `.filter()`. Hope this answers your question

Comment: Had a typo. Edited again